# Como pegar fórmula do Excel no C# utilizando OleDb?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, oledb, fórmula

Preciso pegar a fórmula contida em uma célula do Excel. Estou utilizando OleDb para acessar a planilha, gostaria de saber se tem como utilizá-lo para acessar a fórmula de uma célula?